# Android Studio detects no changes with copied files so can't PUSH to Git

Tags: android, git, android-studio

A very common thing that I tend to do is when I need to update a graphic or something in the drawable-nodpi folder, or any other folder for that matter, Android Studio doesn't detect the change so of course when I try to "PUSH" to GitHub it doesn't actually push and just tosses me the "No Changes Detected" message.

Is there a way to push anyways?  Just to force a commit on specific files that I want to push because I know for a FACT there was a change and I need it submitted?

Lately I been having to delete it first from within Android Studio, then save the file, then add it to GIT then try a commit, but even this works only 70% of the time and is very annoying.

Perfect Example....  I have a splashimage.png in the drawable folder, I am in Photoshop and I change something then do an override to the splashimage.png with my change, but of course Android Studio doesn't see this as a change so I can't Commit this file to Git or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently the item I was looking for was the Synchronize.  I just go to the file and Right Click > Synchronize and it then does a check against the last one manually and see's if it was different. Kind of a Refresh like Kuitsi had stated, but its called Synchronize.  Also some reason I can't get it to work by just clicking Synchronize next to the SAVE icon at the top under File menu.  Not sure why.

Comment: Doesn't help. It's something else. A 3 years old rarely hit bug.

Answer (score 1):

Are you using external editors like photoshop when editing files? If so, press refresh in Android Studio to make it detect changes in file system. Then it says something has changed and suggest you to commit. Of course you can use command line to add changes anyway and commit without even using Android Studio.

Comment: Where do you see a refresh in Android Studio?  Yes I use photoshop to modify the images which I just save and override the already existing file.

Answer (score 0):

Whats your `git status` after you copy the file? Do you commit the changes, before pushing?

Comment: Git Status is unchanged.  Can't commit anything cause there's "no changes detected".

Comment: Um? I can go under View > Recent Changes and android lists an external change, but some reason its not detecting within Android Studio and marketing the file in blue as a changed GIT file.

Comment: May be there is git repo within git repo. Your android studio vcs integration root is different than the git repo you uou are using from terminal.

Answer (score 0):

Have the same problem. Resolved.

The multi-root project used to work just fine for years, detecting changes in sub gits, properly pushing/pulling per sub, but not anymore. After some playing with a broken merge, it has stopped working. And that's not a local git repo issue. Cloned it from scratch - same issue. Changes (doesn't matter internal or external) are not detected by the Studio VCS facility, though git from console shows changes, View/Recent Changes shows them, Local Changes tab doesn't show any (single Default changelist).

It looks like something has happened with the VCS roots detection or related settings. Fixed with Preferences/version Control adding missing roots manually. I wish there is an option to rescan a folder or to delete some settings file and have the studio detecting these roots again.

Comment: Robots everywhere.